# HTML Video Progress Bar Jittery on Mobile (iOS) Devices

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, svelte

I've been working on a custom video player with a progress bar implemented using Svelte. The progress bar updates smoothly using requestAnimationFrame on desktop browsers like Chrome and Firefox. However, when testing on mobile devices (specifically iOS), the progress bar jumps back and forth when seeking forward or backward and when starting the video.
Interestingly, the native progress bar also exhibits this behavior. Can anyone think of a reason for this?

Here's the implementation of a reproduction:

```
<script>
  let video;
  let progress = 0;
  
  function updateProgressBar() {
    if (video && video.duration) {
      progress = (video.currentTime / video.duration) * 100;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(updateProgressBar);
  }

  function onVideoLoad() {
    updateProgressBar();
  }
</script>

<div class="video-container">
  <video
    bind:this="{video}"
    src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4"
    controls
        playsinline
    on:loadedmetadata="{onVideoLoad}"
  ><track kind="captions"/></video>
  <div class="progress-bar" style="width: {progress}%;"></div>
</div>

<style>
  .video-container {
    position: relative;
        max-width: 300px;
  }
    
    video {
        width: 100%;
    }
  
  .progress-bar {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #f00;
  }
</style>
```